# How to resolve Delphi Winsoft Adonis and Borland Data Access components Conflict?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How do i resolve a conflict between Adonis data components and Borland data component.

I have one project that uses the internal Delphi TADOQuery component that has a property Database that connects it to a TDatabase component. Then i have another project that uses TADOQuery from Adonis that has Connection property that connects to the TConnection component.

My problem is, every time i try to open the second project (with Adonis component) it complains it cant find certain property (TADOQuery.Connection) hence cannot compile. How do i disable/Enable the relevant package that i need to use for each project?

Can this two packages live together on the same delphi installation?

Am using Delphi 7 & Adonis 4.4

Gath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time when I have projects like that, I create subclasses of the components for each project.  So in my case I would have TADOQuery with a Database property and TADOQuery with the Connection property.

Of course this might be a bit harder to do in your case since you already have the project, but I would strongly suggest doing something similar.

You can normally desable / enable packages for a specific project by going to the Project Options menu in Delphi and going to Packages and uncheck the packages you don't need in there.

Regards,

Stefaan